# What is a VCS repository?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

This might sound like a stupid question. It's especially stupid since I've used SVN before and I've recently used git.

But I just noticed that I don't exactly know what a repository is.

The way I see it is that a repository is a kind of container to hold the project code. I'm quite certain that's the wrong way to define it.

So how would you define a repository? [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository): `storage location from which software packages may be retrieved and installed on a computer`.

Does that mean you can have more than one project on a repository? 
If so, when would you create a new one?

Comment: A repository is a place where you dump things; books, for example. Wikipedia's definition refers to a place where software packages are stored. A 'VCS repository' is a place where your projects, and their history, are stored.

Answer (score 18):

The Wikipedia definition is correct. Think about a repository from which you would install Linux packages. As far as VCS, it stands for Version Control System and therefore a VCS repository is one for a Version Control System like Git.

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia definition for repository is right. The pro-git book has a [very nice description about VCS](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control). And yes, you can have more than one project in a repository.

Comment: Why would I want more than one project per repository? Isn't it the point to have each project in a different one?

Comment: With `git`, it's uncommon, although possible, to have more than one project per repository - one of the design goals of `git` was to make handling many small single-project repositories a lot easier. In previous days, using something like `cvs` or `svn`, it was a lot more common to have a large-ish centralized repository that contained multiple projects - the centralized structure tended to make that more economical.

Comment: @Shookie it is mostly use case based. You can choose to have a different repository for different projects or one single repository for different projects. I have seen both methods being followed.

Comment: I stumbled upon this old question so I wanted to address: Why would I want more than one project per repository? This practice is often called a [monorepo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo#:~:text=In%20version%2Dcontrol%20systems%2C%20a,commonly%20called%20a%20shared%20codebase) which many company use nowadays. Wikipedia goes over the advantage and disadvantage of such practice